# Searching for Extended English Language Bibles

Tags: reference-request, bible-translation

There are Luther (German) Bible to English parallels out there, however, the Luther Bible includes the Apocryphal texts and the English parallels do not. What I want to know is if there are any English language bibles, which include the Pseudodeuteronomic and Apochryphal texts in their right place as well? Like maybe an "Extended" Bible version that includes all the official as well as all the lost and or excluded texts all in English?

Comment: You mean a Catholic Bible? Or are you talking about more than just the Deuterocanonicalss (like a Bible that includes Enoch and the Gospel of Thomas and Gospel of James, not just the books from the Septuagint left out of in Protestant bibles)?

Comment: Are you asking for a German/English parallel version of the apocryphal books?

Comment: Peter Turner, It would be better if it had all those books you mentioned. However, if it only included the ones left out of the Bible after the Luther Bible, thats fine too.

Comment: read on ebible and biblewebapp https://ebible.org/study/?v3=SR26_29&t3=local%3Aeng-web&w3=bible&v2=SR26_29&t2=local%3Aeng-uk-lxx2012&w2=bible&v1=SR26_29&t1=local%3Agrcbrent&w1=bible

Answer (score 0):

I cannot vouch whatsoever for this translation, but here is [a 120-book volume in English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFXGKLQ2) that has the things that Protestants, Catholics, Eastern and Oriental Orthodox (e.g. Tobit, Judith), and Ethiopian/Tewahedo Orthodox (e.g. Jubilees, Enoch) consider canonical, texts that are not considered canonical but are often included in those groups' manuscripts (e.g. Joseph and Asenath for Armenians), along with some texts that *nobody* considers canonical or deuterocanonical, such as the Didache and the Shepherd of Hermas.